# Improving performance of Laspy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, performance, laspy

I have a working code for a project, but right now to run through the data it would take years to be completed. Please help me to improve it:

```
import laspy
import laspy.file
import numpy as np
```

> (ch1)

```
header = laspy.header.Header()
inFile2 = laspy.file.File("C:\\Users\\Geri\\Desktop\\Sync\\CODETEST\\inverz2.las", mode = "r")
inFile3 = laspy.file.File("C:\\Users\\Geri\\Desktop\\Sync\\CODETEST\\inverz3.las", mode = "r")
inFile = laspy.file.File("C:\\Users\\Geri\\Desktop\\Sync\\CODETEST\\final.las", mode = "rw")
```

> (ch2)

```
point_records = inFile2.points
point_records = inFile3.points
zstarter=3285017.181
zrange=219.768
t=0
```

> (ch3)

```
listx1=np.array([], dtype=float)
listy1=np.array([], dtype=float)
listz1=np.array([], dtype=float)
while t < 1155817:
    z=0
    q=0
    p=0.1
    while z==0:

        xmin=inFile3.x[t]-p
        ymin=inFile3.y[t]-p
        xmax=inFile3.x[t]+p
        ymax=inFile3.y[t]+p
        print t
        n=0
        for points in inFile2.points:
            ax=inFile2.x[n]
            ay=inFile2.y[n]
            if ax > xmin and ax < xmax and ay < ymax and ay > ymin:
```

Till this point the code tries to find the closest neighbor for the input point. The method only works for a data with a few hundred points, but it's too slow for a bigger one.

> (ch4)

```
                                print inFile3.x[t]
                                print inFile2.x[n]
                                newx = [inFile3.x[t]-((inFile3.x[t]-inFile2.x[n])/2)] 
                                newy = [inFile3.y[t]-((inFile3.y[t]-inFile2.y[n])/2)]
```

> (ch5)

```
                                processz = newy-newx


                                ratioz=(processz-zstarter)/zrange
                                newz = [inFile3.z[t]-((inFile3.z[t]-inFile2.z[n])*ratioz)]
```

> (ch6)

```
                                listx1=np.append(listx1, (newx))
                                listy1=np.append(listy1, (newy))
                                listz1=np.append(listz1, (newz))



                                n+=1
                                q+=1
                                t+=1
            else:
                n+=1
                print n
        if q>0 or p==1:            
            z+=1
        else:
            p+=0.1


inFile.x = listx1
inFile.y = listy1
inFile.z = listz1
inFile.close()
```

Unfortunately I can't install the pyflann or the scipy (for k neighboor) to use them so that's why I tried this workaround. I'm wondering if it's posibble to create a buffer around the selected point and just select by that polygon the new point (like in ArcGIS) (FYI I have an ArcGIS 10.2.2 and a standalone python 2.7)

**Description:**
The code ultimate purpose: (gonna label the code with chapters) get 2 las files (ch1) take one of the point from the first one (ch2), find the closest point from the second file (ch3), create a new point based on the two input points (ch4), calculate new z value adjusted by how far is the new point from the edge of the dataset (ch5), save the new point into a new las file (ch6)

Comment: When working with large LAS files, there is going to be more processing time required.  That being said, you have nested loops and print statements.  If you don't need the print statements (i.e. you already know the process works) you could remove them and that should significantly improve the processing time.  You could report at every 10K iterations with something like this: `if not t % 10000: print t`

Comment: My favorite trick for large/very-large processing is adding a periodic check for a "stop.now" file, so that a graceful end to processing can occur it the host needs to be rebooted or the core processing script needs to be updated. Designing the script to be reentrant is a bonus.

Comment: @crmackey Thanks, but while your method makes the process faster, the fact that I run through million points million times makes this code not viable. Right now I'm thinking about to call the Arcpy in and use the Make LAS Dataset Layer (Data Management) ; Select Layer By Location (Data Management)  and Describe (arcpy) functions somehow.

Comment: @Gary I think you're on the right track.  Maybe a good start would be to create a fishnet for the extent of your LAS dataset and make individual las layers within one cell block of the fishnet at a time (maybe use the [extent environment](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000004s000000) and pass in the extent of each feature of the fishnet as you pass through to build each LAS layer).

Comment: It looks like you are saying that the first code block is the bottleneck, but have you used any performance timing code to demonstrate it?  If that is the case then I think you should remove the second block of code to enable potential answerers to focus on just that code snippet.

Comment: Could you please add comments to detail exactly what each section of your code does? A general description would be helpful too.

Comment: @crmackey that sounds a good approach, I'm just wondering if I can make a fishnet like that with about 1000 points in it and doing it by python within in one code then merge those together for the final product (don't want to work with thousands of las files)

Comment: @ PolyGeo You are right, it seems the finding of the second point is the critical part (chapter 3)

Comment: In that case I think you should develop a code snippet that focuses on just that critical part and present just that, instead of your whole code, here.  See http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/tweaking-custom-close-reason-for-poorly-framed-code-debugging-writing-improving